# Cassandra: Find schema name for "drop schema" command

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I can't get the "drop schema" cql command to work, and I'm guessing it's because I'm not providing a schema name. No documentation available is not ambiguous about whether or not the name is necessary, since it all lumps the command description together with "drop keyspace", so while the trailing "keyspace_name" argument should be only for the "drop keyspace" flavor of the command given the name they chose, it could be that a schema name is required for the "drop schema" command. If it is, how can I find the schema name? Can't find a way to do that anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DROP ( KEYSPACE | SCHEMA )  keyspace_name`

Carefully going through [document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/drop_keyspace_r.html) you will find that `SCHEMA` is an alias for `KEYSPACE`

> You can also use the alias DROP SCHEMA.

So `DROP KEYSPACE keyspace_name` AND `DROP SCHEMA keyspace_name` is one and the same

Comment: Ahh, I think you're correct. I read that and was hoping it dropped all keyspaces with one command.